# Nginx Subfolder admin react app under main react app

Tags: reactjs, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I have a situation where i have two apps developed in react.

- User App
- Admin App

I made a build of both apps and have placed the user app build in `site` directory, where as admin app build is inside `site/admin` directory

What i want is

when someone tries `www.mydomain.com/admin`, it should go to admin directory, where as if no admin is given in url then it should not look for admin instead user files should be served.

I am willing to change directory structure any possible way to make this urls work as expected.

I have given alot of time and tries but failed to achieve the result. I am missing something, possibly its related to `try_files` configuration but i am not sure yet.

Following is the Nginx file i have created so far for my needs.

If i write `mydomain.org/admin`, it works fine.

But when i write `mydomain.org/admin/{someotherparam e-g dashboard}`, it loads the main user react app instead of admin app. I guess it reads the index file of user in that case. How to make read the index file of admin if `/admin/` is in the url on first.

I have not much knowledge on nginx configuration, thou i did tried google.

Only 1 task is remaining to do on my part is if i put admin directory and user directory separate.
But then i would have to do domain.org/user and domain.org/admin, which i do not want. 
I want admin react to work only if there is admin in url in first place after url.

I am not sure how to get this to working.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mydomain.org/html/frontend/site;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /admin(.*) {
        root /var/www/mydomain.org/html/frontend/site/admin;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }
}
```

I am using LEMP on ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this config?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
    root /var/www/mydomain.org/html/frontend/site;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks. This did the job.

i can now seem to refresh the admin views, and can directly go to admin urls, also frontend urls working as well.

You are Champion. Awesome. Many Thanks. I thought its not possible and i was trying to move admin folders around :(

Great Help.

Comment: You`re welcome ) You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59992990) where I've tried to explain why this nginx behavior is happened and what solutions can be used.