# nginx 2 locations for different apps (react and angular)

Tags: angular, reactjs, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a React application and an admin dashboard which is built in Angular:

> **/var/www/example.com/example/web** <- React
>
> **/var/www/example.com/example/admin** <- Angular

This is my Nginx config:

```
server {

   server_name example.com;
   index index.html index.htm;

   # React
   location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/example/web/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   # Admin
   location /admin {
        root /var/www/example.com/example/admin/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}
```

When I navigate to **`example.com/admin`** it redirects me to the react application instead of the angular one.

I know this may have been asked a lot before but I've been trying to fix this all day with no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior occures because the last argument of [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive must be an URI or the HTTP error code. In your case, by processing request `http://example.com/admin` resulting URI of the second `try_files` directive will be `/index.html`, which is in next turn will be processed with first location block and leads you to react application.

One solution is to put angular application into the `admin` folder of the react application folder:

```
server {

   server_name example.com;
   index index.html index.htm;
   # React folder
   root /var/www/example.com/example/web/build;

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   # Admin
   location /admin {
        # angular app must be in the /var/www/example.com/example/web/build/admin folder
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
   }
}
```

This way resulting URI of the second `try_files` directive will be `/admin/index.html`, which leads you to angular application index file.

The second solution is to use an [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive for the second location block:

```
server {

   server_name example.com;
   index index.html index.htm;

   # React
   location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/example/web/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   # Admin
   location /admin {
        alias /var/www/example.com/example/admin/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
   }
}
```

Note that resulting URI of the `http://example.com/admin` request will be `/admin/index.html`, which still will be processed by the second location block and served with the file `/var/www/example.com/example/admin/dist/index.html` (if I use `root` directive instead of `alias` one, location prefix `/admin` will be added to the path and the index file will be searched in the `/var/www/example.com/example/admin/dist/admin` folder).

In both cases the absence of angular app index file in the folder in which nginx will look for it would be the reason of nginx HTTP 500 error because of infinite redirection to `/admin/index.html` URI.

Comment: Thanks A LOT! Second solution worked but I didn't have to add `/admin/index.html`

Comment: @ekclone This is because your index file found via `index` directive in your angular app root folder. You'll see the difference if you try something like `http://example.com/admin/test` request. My config will lead you to angular index file, yours one to react index file.